# How to find which socket descriptor had become invalid in fdset

Tags: sockets, select

In the server side while doing select() on readfds it returns bad file descriptor error.How can i find which of the fd has become invalid in fdset?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when a connection on the other side is closed or an RST segment is sent, `select` returns and marks the corresponding descriptors as ready for read. When you subsequently perform `read`/`recv` from them, an error or EOF is returned.

You might also try using `strace` tool (if available) for debugging. It will help you keep track of what descriptors are fed to `select` and what descriptors `read`/`recv` are called with.

Comment: In the code once i face this error ...if i iterate through each fd in fdset and do fcntl() on each will i be able to find which fd had become invalid.

Comment: Typically, you iterate through all descriptors that are marked as ready in resulting read fdset and read from them the data you need. If you happen to get `-1` after read (or 0, signalizing that a peer closed the socket), this means the error has occurred and you shouldn't include this descriptor to read fdset before the next invocation of `select`.

Comment: No..If i get an error in select ..ill do fcntl on each fd in fdset..will that help?

Comment: You might detect that something is wrong with the descriptor this way, however I've never seen this kind of manipulations. If `select` returns `EBADF`, it typically means that you have provided it with an invalid descriptor. The fact that it's invalid (nonexistent file descriptor, closed descriptor or the one on which the error occurred) should be determined earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can check pending error on a socket with the following function:

```
int get_socket_error( int s )  {
    int error;
    socklen_t len = sizeof( error );
    if ( getsockopt( s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len ) < 0 ) 
        error = errno;
    return error;
}
```

But as @Maxim is saying, having `EBADF` returned from [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) is usually an indication of a sloppy coding,

Comment: ok..1 basic question...Is it possible to iterate through fdset ..any knows the structure of fdset...cannot find it.

Comment: Typically, fdset is a bitmap where each bit shows whether the descriptor is ready or not. However, you shouldn't rely on the internal implementation of fdset and use the macros for manipulating it (`FD_ISSET` etc). A usual way is a loop from 0 to `max_fd + 1` checking with `FD_ISSET` macro whether the descriptor is ready for IO. The current variable you are iterating with conains a file descriptor.

Comment: If you are on Linux, switch to `epoll(7)`. You won't have to re-populate wait list on every iteration, and `close(2)`-ed sockets are automatically removed from the poll set.

Comment: ok..in the case of windows can i use ioctlsocket() to check whether a socket is valid or not?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know Windows, but you are trying to solve the wrong problem - fix your socket handling.